# What is wrong with this module?

Tags: python

I have triple checked the syntax on this python module statement, and it is NOT working...

```
correct = 0
ahtriggercount = 0

def IsCorrect():
    #Increase correct count.
    correct = correct + 1
    #Lower autohelp trigger count.
    if ahtriggercount > 0:
        ahtriggercount = ahtriggercount - 1
```

The general "syntax error" (no further information is being given by the IDE) is being thrown at...

```
if ahtriggercount > 0:
```

What is wrong? Why can't we access the ahtriggercount variable?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: If you want help always always include the error. Better yet read the error, and it probably tells you what the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell python that you're accessing a global variable. Like this:

```
correct = 0
ahtriggercount = 0

def IsCorrect():
    global correct, ahtriggercount
    #Increase correct count.
    correct = correct + 1
    #Lower autohelp trigger count.
    if ahtriggercount > 0:
        ahtriggercount = ahtriggercount - 1
```

Global variables are read-only by default unless you use the **global** declaration.

You also had a whitespace issue. There were some strange spaces on one of the lines. When I deleted the spaces and added them again, I stopped getting IndentationError.

Comment: Still no dice. We declared the variables as global exactly as described, and it is still throwing the same syntax error. Ehhhhhhh???

Comment: It just says "invalid syntax", no further data. Is it even possible to declare a variable at the top of a standalone module?

Comment: You had some incorrect whitespace. I've corrected it above. If you copy and paste this into the interpreter, it works correctly now.

Comment: Redesigned my code a bit, and used the global statement as necessary. TY. It is always an adventure learning a new language.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare ahtriggercount and correct as global because you are modifying their value.

```
def IsCorrect():
    global ahtriggercount, correct
    #Increase correct count.
    correct = correct + 1
    #Lower autohelp trigger count.
    if ahtriggercount > 0:
        ahtriggercount = ahtriggercount - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the error message we can only guess. However, your snippet seems to be syntactically correct. Maybe you mixed up spaces and tabs or forgat a space or tab in one line? Right indentation is crucial in Python.